# I have an error "Content type not set" when testing with junit

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit

I use spring boot 2.7 and test with junit
during the execution of the tests I get an error :
the other tests work well.

controller

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/employees")
public ResponseEntity<Employee> addEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody EmployeeDto employeeDto) {

    Optional<Employee> employeeDb = employeeService.findByEmail(employeeDto.getEmail());

    // must not exist in database
    if (!employeeDb.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }

    // convertion dto -> model
    Employee employee = employeeDto.toEmployee();

    return new ResponseEntity<>(employeeService.save(employee), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

controllerTest

```java
@Test
void addEmployee() throws Exception {

    when(employeeService.save(employeeDto.toEmployee())).thenReturn(employee);
    when(employeeService.findByEmail(any(String.class))).thenReturn(Optional.of(employee));

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(employeeDto);

    mockMvc.perform(
        MockMvcRequestBuilders
        .post(REST_URL)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .characterEncoding("utf-8")
        .content(json)
    )
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.firstname", is(employee.getFirstname())))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.lastname", is(employee.getLastname())))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.email", is(employee.getEmail())));
}
```

the error : "Content type not set"
yet in the test I indicate well the content-type : ".contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)"

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /api/employees/
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Accept:"application/json", Content-Length:"74"]
             Body = {"email":"test1@test.com","firstname":"firstname1","lastname":"lastname1"}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.acme.app1.controllers.EmployeeController
           Method = com.acme.app1.controllers.EmployeeController#addEmployee(EmployeeDto)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Content type not set

    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:37)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertTrue(AssertionErrors.java:70)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertNotNull(AssertionErrors.java:106)
```

for the test to be successful, what should I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content type you've set is used for the request, but in your assertion you're checking for the content type which is returned in the response.

As you can see in the log, there is no content type or body set in the MockHttpServletResponse:

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
       Status = 200
Error message = null
      Headers = []
 Content type = null
         Body = 
Forwarded URL = null
```

Redirected URL = null
Cookies = []

So there seems to be an issue with the returned object in your mocked result of

```
when(employeeService.save(employeeDto.toEmployee())).thenReturn(employee);
```

since the result of this will be rendered to a JSON object you're doing your assertions on.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue related to `Content-Type` while writing test.
I was writing test for REST controller. I had mockbean of my service when ever I was trying to access my service method my service method was iterating the list then matching the `id` and then returned me a object but when I was writing test, I was not using let list, just passing single object that was causing the issue of `Content-Type`. I hope this might help.

***Note***: I was not using repository. I was using hardcoded values in my services.